# How to properly insert .tikz file using \graphicspath?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get the following tikz file to run

```
% Red-black tree
% Author: Madit
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I am getting the error:
`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/arn_r'`

I have taken this from:

https://texample.net/tikz/examples/red-black-tree/

where it seems to compile OK using the online compiler. I cannot see where my error is?

I think my error is to with the way that I am inserting the .tikz file into my document. I have done it previously this way but it seems to not be working this time:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c ccc c}
        & &\includegraphics[height=4cm]{redblack.tikz} & &\\
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Balanced tree with coloured nodes indicating matching predictors. \cite{tikztree}}
    \label{7:tree1}
\end{figure*}
```

When I did this previously I used `\tikzstyle{}` not `\tikzset{}`. I think it is here that I am missing something.

Changing `\includegraphics[height=4cm]{redblack.tikz}` to `\input{/filepath/redblack.tex}` did not help and I got exactly the same errors with all of the instances of the styles except 'treenode' which is only used within `\tikzset{}`

However, compiling the standalone document does work. So I guess there is something about the way I am inserting the .tikz file and/or .tex document?

Comment: the above code compiles fine

Comment: remove all references of `arn_r` from the code after `begindocument`  -- now see if it compiles

Comment: Please show the full log of your compilation of the MWE above that you say give errors. It get the same result as JS (need need to get mad at someone trying to help). What exactly is in that `.tikz` image you are trying to include? Normally tikz code is pure LaTeX and thus needs to be included as pure LaTeX. So please explain what exactly it is you are doing in the last half of your question as we do not understand what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the way I was inserting the document. I was using the original file, including `\documentclass`, as well as `\begin` and `\end`. Actually, to use `\graphicspath` and `.tikz` you need to use the following version:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
        level distance = 1.5cm}]

%tikzset
\tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
        font=\sffamily},
    arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
        fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
    arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
        text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
    arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
        minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}
 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
        child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
            child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                {$x$}} %for a named pointer
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {20}
            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
        child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {51}
            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I hope this helps someone `cos it cost me a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to include TikZ pictures into a larger document is the `standalone` document class.

The `standalone` class has two primary use cases, only one of which I see used commonly. The most common use is when you want to product a closely cropped pdf of the TeX output (e.g. PDF cropped to just the content of a TikZ picture). This is invoked by the `documentclass`. The great thing about this approach is it lets you iterate on a single picture without compiling the entire document.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A lesser known feature, although it's right in the `standalone` manual, is that a `standalone` class document that's included into a larger document (that's loaded the `standalone` package) will *remove* the preamble and `document` environment and insert just the text of the "standalone document". This allows you to do things like abstract your TikZ settings into a preamble file, include it in each drawing you make, and still include them in the main document with no additional effort. You can even set the `standalone` class to collect and sort the preambles of the included files instead of removing them.

As an example you could adjust your example like this:

tikzsetup.tex:

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}
```

red-black-tikz.tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\include{tikzsetup.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

red-black-main.tex

```latex
% Red-black tree
% Author: Madit
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\include{tikzsetup}

\begin{document}
Some main text describing red-black trees:
\include{red-black-tikz.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\include` is wrong here. In the preamble, LaTeX warns you about this. In the main document, it will give undesirable results.